# SQL to identify rows with price changes, group by item

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with thousands of entries for fruit items. Some fruit items sell right away, others get re-priced at a subsequent date at a lower price to clear inventory. Each item entry has a unique id / SKU but gets a new row ID when it's re-entered at a new price.

```
Original Table                  
ID  Date    UID Fruit   Variety Price
1   3/1/18  100100  Apple   Fiji    2.99
2   3/1/18  100101  Apple   Gala    3.99
3   3/1/18  100102  Apple   HoneyCrisp  4.99
4   3/1/18  100201  Orange  Navel   2.49
5   3/1/18  100202  Orange  Clementine  2.79
6   3/1/18  100301  Cherry  Bing    1.99
7   3/1/18  100302  Cherry  Black   2.29
8   3/8/18  100100  Apple   Fiji    2.69
9   3/8/18  100202  Orange  Clementine  2.15
10  3/15/18 100302  Cherry  Black   1.79
11  3/22/18 100102  Apple   HoneyCrisp  4.49
12  3/29/18 100201  Orange  Navel   2.19
```

And I am looking for output that lists the items that have had price changes, grouped by UID so that items that have re-priced show up in rows next to each other so its easy to view the comparison in the price change, like so:

```
Desired Results                 
ID  Date    UID Fruit   Variety Price
1   3/1/18  100100  Apple   Fiji    2.99
8   3/8/18  100100  Apple   Fiji    2.69
5   3/1/18  100202  Orange  Clementine  2.79
9   3/8/18  100202  Orange  Clementine  2.15
7   3/1/18  100302  Cherry  Black   2.29
10  3/15/18 100302  Cherry  Black   1.79
3   3/1/18  100102  Apple   HoneyCrisp  4.99
11  3/22/18 100102  Apple   HoneyCrisp  4.49
4   3/1/18  100201  Orange  Navel   2.49
12  3/29/18 100201  Orange  Navel   2.19
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
select t.ID, t.Date, t.UID, t.Fruit, t.Variety, t.Price
from tbl t 
join (
    select UID 
    from tbl 
    group by UID 
    having count(1) >= 2
) t2 
on t2.UID = t.UID 
where t.Fruit = 'Apple' -- if you want to filter by a particular fruit
order by t.UID, t.Date
```

Basically, you're just joining the table to a sub-set of itself, where that sub-set represents any items whose UID occurs multiple times in the table.

Of course, you'll need to substitute in actual column and table names.

EDIT: Window functions are probably the best way to achieve your second desired result-set:

```
select q.UID, q.Fruit, q.Variety, avg(percent_drop) 
from (
    select t.*
    , t2.price as reduced_price
    , (t.price - t2.price)::NUMERIC(10,2) as price_drop
    , (1 - (t2.price / t.price::FLOAT))::NUMERIC(10, 2) as percent_drop
    from (
      select row_number() over (partition by t.UID order by t.Date), t.* 
      from tbl t
    ) t
    join (
      select row_number() over (partition by t.UID order by t.Date), t.* 
      FROM tbl t
    ) t2
    on t2.UID = t.UID 
    and t2.row_number = t.row_number + 1
) q
group by q.UID, q.Fruit, q.Variety
```

Note that this again joins the table against itself, but this time it looks for its nearest "neighboring" row, by virtue of the date. Note this query works regardless of whether a price is increased or decreased, but the column aliases assume that prices are decreased when an item is re-added at a later date. Currently the outer query groups by UID, Fruit, and Variety, to see the average % price drop on a per-UID basis, but you could see the average across *all products* simply by not doing any grouping at all in the outer query.

Comment: Great, thanks! Now what if I want to do this same query but only show results where Fruit = Apple? (So the results output would have 4 rows:
1   3/1/18  100100  Apple   Fiji    2.99
8   3/8/18  100100  Apple   Fiji    2.69
3   3/1/18  100102  Apple   HoneyCrisp  4.99
11  3/22/18 100102  Apple   HoneyCrisp  4.49

Comment: No problem! If you want to only show results where Fruit = Apple, you would just add an appropriate `WHERE` clause after the `JOIN` clause but before the `ORDER BY` clause. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Okay, to add some complexity, let's say that I now want to calculate the average price drop across all price changes. So it would basically calculate each percentage price change and then average that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new query to address your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using window functions:

```
select ID, Date, UID, Fruit, Variety, Price
from (select t.*,
             min(t.price) over (partition by t.fruit, t.variety) as min_price,
             max(t.price) over (partition by t.fruit, t.variety) as max_price
      from t 
     ) t
where min_price <> max_price
order by fruit, variety, date;
```

Comment: The big advantage here is that the table is only scanned once.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use *Windows function* on subquery.

You can put your condition on `where` clause

Then self join.

```
SELECT  t.ID, t.Date, t.UID, t.Fruit, t.Variety, t.Price
FROM 
(
   SELECT uid,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by UID ORDER BY UID, Date) RK
   FROM T
)t2 INNER JOIN t t on t.uid = t2.uid AND RK >= 2
order by t.UID, t.Date
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/755a0/22*

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
WITH FDATA AS(
SELECT 1 "ID",   CAST('2018/01/03' AS DATE) DT,  100100 "UID",  'Apple' FRUIT,   'Fiji' VARIETY,  '2.99' PRICE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2   , CAST('2018/01/03' AS DATE)  , 100101,  'Apple'  ,  'Gala'        ,'3.99' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 3   , CAST('2018/01/03' AS DATE)  , 100102,  'Apple'  ,  'HoneyCrisp'  ,'4.99' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 4   , CAST('2018/01/03' AS DATE)  , 100201,  'Orange' ,  'Navel'      , '2.49' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 5   , CAST('2018/01/03' AS DATE)  , 100202,  'Orange' ,  'Clementine'  ,'2.79' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 6   , CAST('2018/01/03' AS DATE)  , 100301,  'Cherry' ,  'Bing'       , '1.99' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 7   , CAST('2018/01/03' AS DATE)  , 100302,  'Cherry' ,  'Black'      , '2.29' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 8   , CAST('2018/03/08' AS DATE)  , 100100,  'Apple'  ,  'Fiji'       , '2.69' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 9   , CAST('2018/03/08' AS DATE)  , 100202,  'Orange' ,  'Clementine' , '2.15' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 10  , CAST('2018/03/15' AS DATE)  , 100302,  'Cherry' ,  'Black'      , '1.79' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 11  , CAST('2018/03/22' AS DATE)  , 100102,  'Apple'  ,  'HoneyCrisp' , '4.49' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 12  , CAST('2018/03/29' AS DATE)  , 100201,  'Orange' ,  'Navel'      , '2.19' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 13   , CAST('2018/03/10' AS DATE)  , 100301,  'Cherry' ,  'Bing'       , '1.99' FROM DUAL
UNION        
SELECT 14   , CAST('2018/03/30' AS DATE)  , 100100,  'Apple'  ,  'Fiji'       , '3.19' FROM DUAL
)--SELECT "UID", FRUIT, VARIETY, PRICE, DT, MIN(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, FRUIT, VARIETY) MIN_PRICE, MAX(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, FRUIT, VARIETY) MAX_PRICE FROM FDATA;
SELECT
"ID", DT, "UID", FRUIT, VARIETY, PRICE
FROM(
SELECT 
"ID", "UID", FRUIT, VARIETY, PRICE, DT, MAX(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, FRUIT, VARIETY) - MIN(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, FRUIT, VARIETY) CHG
FROM FDATA)
WHERE CHG > 0
ORDER BY "UID", DT;
```